# Is There Any Way To Speed Up SQLite Fetch?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite

Is There Any Way To Speed Up SQLite Fetch?
I am fetching data from my SQLite database into an array which loads my tableView.

It is taking around 10-20 seconds to populate the array. Is there a quicker way to do this or something? Perhaps only load each cell at a time so atleast the user sees some cells while the rest are loading?

Here is the code in my ViewController:
Code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myThread:) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 
}
-(void) myThread:(id) obj {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[Database sharedDatabase] getICD9DiseaseCodes];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataDoneLoading:) withObject:array waitUntilDone:NO];
    [pool release];    
}

-(void) dataDoneLoading:(id) obj {
    NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *) obj;
    self.codeAray = array;
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

Here is the code from the actual fetch:
Code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) getICD9ProcedureCodes
{
    sqlite3 *database = CodesDatabase();
    NSMutableArray *icd9ProcedureCodes = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSString *nsquery = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT code, title, description FROM icd9_procedure_codes"];
    const char *query = [nsquery UTF8String];
    [nsquery release];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    int prepareCode = (sqlite3_prepare_v2( database, query, -1, &statement, NULL));
    if(prepareCode == SQLITE_OK) {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            ICD9DiseaseCodes *code = [[ICD9DiseaseCodes alloc] init];
            code.code = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            code.name = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            code.description = [NSString stringWithCString:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            [icd9ProcedureCodes addObject:code];
            [code release];
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    return icd9ProcedureCodes;
}
```

Comment: How many rows are in the table? You might want to consider using [NSFetchedResultsController](http://maniacdev.com/2010/01/core-data-nsfetchedresultscontroller/).

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController will handle loading only the rows you need. You will need to convert to using CoreData to access the sqlite database.

Comment: Brian, I've used core data before in other apps but I've never been able to load an existing database into it successfully because it has the extra Z columns. Have you actually done this?

Comment: No, I haven't done that. My best guess would be to create a CoreData implementation with database to get a database with the Z columns, then write a program/script to copy the data from the existing database into the CoreData sqlite database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely only load those rows that you need. Use the SQL LIMIT and OFFSET options to load only what you need.

I don't know offhand if reading a single row at a time will be fast enough, but it's worth a try. Something like:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT code, title, description FROM icd9_procedure_codes ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1 OFFSET %d", indexPath.row];

   // perform your database SELECT operation here

   // set up your UITableViewCell with whatever results you want to display
   cell.textLabel.text = code.name;
}
```

You should also make sure that you reuse UITableViewCells in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Hey Eric, so are you saying to perform the code thats in my `-(NSMutableArray *) getICD9ProcedureCodes` method here?  That stuff is in it's own NSObject class though

Comment: I'm saying that you should only read one record at a time as needed rather than all at once. I think it will probably be very quick to display the table. I can't really tell from the code whether you really need all of the records in memory at one time. For example, if the user taps on the UITableViewCell with indexPath.row = 40, you can always just read that record from sqlite with "SELECT code, title, description FROM icd9_procedure_codes ORDER BY ROWID LIMIT 1 OFFSET 40". (Alternatively, you can subclass UITableViewCell and attach an ICD9DiseaseCodes object to it).